# Build photo editor interface using Qt

Tags: qt, pyqt

I would like to create an application using Qt (PyQt5 specifically) that has a photo editor like interface. More specifically, I would like it to have:

- No main window
- Free-floating toolbar
- Free-floating context window
- Startup dialog
- Edit-windows

[image: Example Photo Editor Interface (Acorn)]

The idea is to have the toolbar and context window persist for as along as the application is running. The user then opens one or multiple documents (e.g. images in the photo editor example) and uses the options in the toolbar to modify the document(s).

My first question is; does this type of application interface have a specific name, something akin to MDI or SDI? I've been searching for "photo editor interface" and variations on that, but haven't been able to find a search string that seems to hit the mark. For instance, I've tried "build a photo editor type interface with Qt" but it doesn't yield anything useful.

The second question I have is, what is the best way to build a Qt application that doesn't spawn a main window? It seems like I could kludge an assortment of dialogs together to make this happen, but I would really like to use a lot of the functionality of QMainWindow (toolbars, menus, top-level management of the application). Is there a way to launch QMainWindow, display the menu and toolbar, but suppress the main window?

I plan to primarily use this application on OSX, but would also like it to perform well on Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

QMenuBar has explicit support for OSX to have the menu bar behave as expected: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenubar.html#qmenubar-on-os-x

I think it'll also work on Ubuntu's Unity, which tries to have similar style, but there may be some details you need to take care of. Other desktops should work as expected.

As to how to have individual windows: any Qt widget will be a top level window if it has no parent, so that is an easy way to create windows. If you want to have parent windows (for example to control window stacking order automatically), there's a window flag for that. So you don't need to use QDialog (not sure if you were implying that in your question).

You want to read [QWidget documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#details) carefully to get an idea how all this works.

Comment: Any thoughts on the best way to piece together an application without using a main window? Notice on the Acorn screen shot that neither the editor or context windows have (X) buttons; the way to exit the application is through the file menu. I'd like to replicate this somehow; like have a menubar, a toolbar, but no main window.

Comment: Why you dont want main window? U can make mainWindow subclass and just hide close window button, U can make as many main windows as u want making them also dockwidget areas so you cand rag/drop icons on the window/between window  to  re-arrange sub tools. Etc etc etc.